# Django - Cancel one delivery but when cancelling one it cancels all the deliveries

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to cancel one "posted" delivery when the user clicks on the button "cancel", but it cancels all the posted deliveries below is the views.py .

[views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xubxC.png)

```
def current_delivery_page(request):
deliveries = Delivery.objects.filter(
    restaurant = request.user.restaurant,
    status_of_delivery__in=[
        Delivery.DELIVERY_DELIVERING,
        Delivery.DELIVERY_POSTED
    ]
)

delivery = Delivery.objects.all()

for a in delivery:
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.POST['receipt_number']:
        a.status_of_delivery = Delivery.DELIVERY_CANCELLED
        a.save()

return render(request, 'restaurant/deliveries.html',
{
    "deliveries": deliveries
})
```

[html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RpBo.png)

```
{% if d.status_of_delivery == 'posted' %}
     <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" 
          name="update">Cancel</button>
        <input type="hidden" value="{{ d.receipt_number }}" 
          name="receipt_number">
      </form>
{% endif %}
```

Models:

[image: models]

Here is the list of deliveries:

[image: Here is the list of deliveries]

I want to cancel one delivery and it automatically moves to the "Done/Cancelled Deliveries" page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are looping through all `Delivery` instances in the database and setting all their status to `DELIVERY_CANCELED` in your `for a in delivery` loop.

You need to use `Delivery.objects.get(pk=request.POST.get('receipt_number'))` to fetch the delivery instance you need and then set its status to canceled. You could do something like this:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    delivery = get_object_or_404(Delivery, pk=request.POST.get('receipt_number'))
    if delivery:
        delivery.status_of_delivery = Delivery.DELIVERY_CANCELED
        delivery.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check if `receipt_numer` from POST is equal to delivery instance `receipt_number`

```
for a in delivery:
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.POST['receipt_number'] == a.receipt_number:
        a.status_of_delivery = Delivery.DELIVERY_CANCELLED
        a.save()
```

Comment: Hey man, thanks for the reply, I tried your suggestion but it didn't seem to work, no delivery was cancelled.

Comment: What does it mean that it doesn't work? Still all instances are cancelled?

Comment: No instances are being cancelled.

Comment: What is a value of `request.POST['receipt_number']` and are you sure that delivery instance with this uuid exists?

Comment: The receipt_number is the id, it is autogenerated by default and it's unique, yes it does exists. I have attached screen grabs of the uuid from the database and frontend in the question above